# How to split a String containing special character in Java

Tags: java

I want to split one string containing value `"/ASR/Os_0?type=EcuValues"` to extract the contents before `"?type=EcuValues"` from the string. I tried :

```
String stringArray[] = stringValue.split("?type=EcuValues")
```

but I am getting exception.

Comment: Your string appears to be from a URL In that case, I would suggest you to use `java.net.URL`

Comment: 'I am getting exception' is not a problem description.

Answer (score 2):

Use string split

```
    String s =  "/ASR/Os_0?type=EcuValues" 


    String temp[] =  s.split("?");

//u will get the required chars in temp array
```

Comment: SORRY,was thinking something else. Though, +1...

Answer (score 0):

[`String#split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) takes a regex, `?` is a [metacharacter](https://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/regular-expression/metacharacter-list.php) with special meaning. You should do:

```
String[] test2 = test.split(Pattern.quote("?type=EcuValues"));
//quote returns string representation of the regex
```

Or simply escaping the `?`:

```
String[] test2 = test.split("\\?type=EcuValues");
```